# How to set column title for using it in blade template?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to set title text for each $fillable

for using it in templates when I foreaching $fillable I want something like this:

```
@foreach($user->getFillable() as $field)
   Title: {{$user->titles->$field}} value: {{$user->$field}}<br>
@endforeach
```

I understant that we can create array in model class and fill it with titles, but it will double code for $fillable var. Maybe we can do this any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach($user->getAttributes() as $attribute => $value)
   Title: {{ $attribute }} value: {{ $value }}<br>
@endforeach
```

Or In model

```
public $titles = [
    'attribute_name' => 'Attribute Name',
    'attribute' => 'Corespond Title',
    ................
];

public function getTitle($attribute) 
{
    return $this->titles[$attribute] ?? title_case($attribute);
}
```

Usage

```
@foreach($user->getAttributes() as $attribute => $value)
   Title: {{ $user->getTitle($attribute) }} value: {{ $value }}<br>
@endforeach
```

Also can make it in lang files
in **resources/lang/en** make **attributes.php**

```
[
    'attribute_name' => 'Attribute Name',
    'attribute' => 'Corespond Title',

]
```

Usage

```
@foreach($user->getAttributes() as $attribute => $value)
   Title: {{ __('attributes.'. $attribute) }} value: {{ $value }}<br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: $value is just a column name and not fully human readable, I want translate it and assign new title

Comment: getFillable must be getAttributes()

Comment: It works as expected, so no other way as I see... Thank you for detailed code, always forgetting about getters and wondering why object->var not working ))